# Measure two events with universal analytics

Tags: events, google-analytics, universal-analytics, event-tracking

I have this code:

```
<script src='//embed.bannerflow.com/5517386c738045256c6312be' onLoad="ga('send', 'event', 'banner', 'impression', 'kubo');" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'banner', 'click', 'kubo');"></script>
```

What I am trying to do is to track impression and clicks on a banner in my website. Right now the impressions and being tracked fine in google analytics. They show in real time events, but the onclick is not working and I need to know how to do this correctly. I need to measure these two things for the same banner.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The onclick attribnute can't be applied to the script element.

Comment: Also the onclick syntax is correct and just needs to be put into the img or a tags for that particular banner.

Comment: Could you help me understand where or how I can add the onclick? I just have a <script> or <iframe> format for the banner.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an anchor tag for your banner, you can add your onclick in there. This way, whoever clicks on the banner will trigger an event to fire. It could look something like this:

```
<a href="yourbannerlink.html" id="banner" onload="ga('send', 'event', 'banner', 'impression', 'kubo');ga('send', 'event', 'banner', 'click', 'kubo');"><img src="banner.jpg"></a>
```

Note that this is not verified, and you should test it out.